# Jupyter book with MyBinder launch button

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyterbook, mybinder

I published on GitHub pages a Jupyter book that contains launch buttons for MyBinder for Jupyter notebook files.

The _config.yml file contains:

```
launch_buttons:
    notebook_interface: "jupyterlab"
    binderhub_url: "https://mybinder.org"
```

I built a static website with the command `$ jupyter-book build <directory>` then I imported the site on github pages with the command `$ ghp_import -n -p -f _build/html`.

The problem is that when the notebook is launched in MyBinder, there is the error message

```
Cannot open
Could not find path: docs/<file_name>.ipynb 
                             Dismiss
```

Is it possible to set the button (that launches MyBinder) so that to launch MyBinder in the folder of the root (main branch) of the GitHub repository in which the <file_name>.ipynb exists? (i.e., on which the static web site was built)